# Jenkins - build to be success rather than unstable when failed tests

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that runs tests using the `dotnet test` command. Some of these are UI tests that run using Selenium and aren't entirely reliable. We have therefore built a mechanism where if some of the tests fail then those tests are rerun again. If the tests pass the second time then they are considered a success. It's not a great approach, but prevents us wasting a lot of time investigating test failures that run successfully the next time.

When a build runs and Jenkins reruns some of the tests and they pass the second time the build is marked as UNSTABLE rather than SUCCESS. This is annoying as it shows as a failure in our source control (BitBucket) and ultimately we consider the build a success. It also prevents us from auto merging the branch using Renovate.

How can we override the result to set this to SUCCESS rather than UNSTABLE. I tried adding the step below after the tests, but this didn't change the outcome.

```
stage('Set Result'){
        steps{
            script{
                currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
            }
        }
    }
```

Are there any other approaches to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `post` section of the build, you can declare:

```
post {
    unstable {
        script {
            currentBuild.rawBuild.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
        }
    }
}
```

When you run the build, the job will fail and you need to go into the console output and do in-process script approval. Run it again and it will fail once again, and you have to do in-process script approval for a second script. Now when you run the build here on-wards, the build will succeed when you get an unstable result.